# WCF service authentication by SessionId

Tags: wcf, authentication

I want to authenticate a WPF client through Session Management.
Firstly, user with the help of a wpf form will access the WCF service and will generate a seesion ID and if user again want to access the service, instead of authenticating using username and password we would like to authenticate, using the seesion ID which was generated in the previous step.

So kindly suggest what could be the best possible way to get a desired output?

I am not using the web.config file. Instead I am using configuration part in C# code which is below:-

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode=SessionMode.Required)] 
public interface Iexecute { 
    [OperationContract] 
    string loginUserName(); 

    [OperationContract] 
    string LoginPassword(string SessionId); 
} 

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerSession)] 
public class Execute : Iexecute, IDisposable
```

Another part of configuartion is :-

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Execute), new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:4233"))) { host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(Iexecute), new NetTcpBinding(), "Execute"); 
NetTcpBinding tcpsessionBinding = new NetTcpBinding(); tcpsessionBinding.ReliableSession.Enabled = true; tcpsessionBinding.ReliableSession.InactivityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(25);
```

Comment: Are you talking about accessing the same service/method once using username/password and then using sessionId?

Comment: Yes,you are right Kangkan.But I dont know whether this is the right way to implement the authentication service. So could you provide me the best way to implement authentication(It could be done either with the help of user authentication or sessionId generation)

Comment: But what is the motivation for such a requirement? Do you want to have some session on the service? What is the problem if the authentication happens the same way as of the first time? After all that is transparent to the user.

Comment: Actually I was thinking for the performance issue. Probably, it would take less time if I compare SessionId each time rather than matching the Username and Password each time. So doesn't it make sense?

Comment: If you wish to have session Id and the same to be valid on the service side, you need a service set for per-session, that normally takes more resources (so slower speed on the same machine) when you copare the default service setting of per-call. If you do not need a session to be live, there is no point os session for just authentication. The trade-off between having a per-session service for the authentication will be negative looking at the overhead of username/password authentication.

Comment: Actually there are 3 clients accessing a single service and I want each of them to maintain a session with the service part and generate a sessionID and that session will not terminate until the proxy is destroyed. So that sessionID will be used to authenticate every client individually.And according to your opinion per session will be a good option.  But when I am doing with per-session,Service is generating a single instance each time and every client is getting the same SessionID. May be I am doing mistake in the configuration part..

Comment: Show your configuration. Is it per session? If yes, the authentication will take place once only.

Comment: I am not using the web.config file.  Instead I am using configuration part in C# code which is below:-                        [ServiceContract(SessionMode=SessionMode.Required)]
    public interface Iexecute
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string loginUserName();
        [OperationContract]
        string LoginPassword(string SessionId);
    }
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
   public class Execute : Iexecute, IDisposable

Comment: Another part of configuartion is :-            ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Execute),
                                          
                                                        new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:4233")))
            {
                host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(Iexecute), new NetTcpBinding(), "Execute");
                NetTcpBinding tcpsessionBinding = new NetTcpBinding();
                tcpsessionBinding.ReliableSession.Enabled = true;
                tcpsessionBinding.ReliableSession.InactivityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(25);

Comment: Please update your post!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use session for wcf service then you have to use single proxy for service in client side.One more proxy from same client for same service will create a new session.Its better to use singleton proxy in client may satisfy your need.

Refer this ling for WCF Session and Instance management

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163590.aspx#S2

Comment: Yes,you are right Kangkan.But I dont know whether this is the right way to implement the authentication service. So could you provide me the best way to implement authentication(It could be done either with the help of user authentication or sessionId generation)